# referencing array element(jquery)

Tags: jquery, arrays

How do you refer to elements of array in Jquery? For instance - input type of text with name="a[]" attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select them with an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) on the `name` attribute, like this:

```
$("input[name='a[]']")
```

This will get you all elements, if you want one at a specific index as a jQuery object use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), or as a DOM element use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), like this:

```
$("input[name='a[]']").eq(0)  //first element wrapped in jQuery object
$("input[name='a[]']").get(0) //first raw DOM element
```

Comment: Nitpicking: Since it was also specified that the input type be limited to text, the more correct selector would be $("input[name='a[]'][type=text]").